# ssis convert data from source to destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the below data in an excel source:

```
Date: 1-Jun-15
Received: 10
Answered: 9
AvgWaitTime: 0:00:05
AvgHandleTime: 0:00:07
Abandoned: 1
```

The destination table is as below:

```
Date date,
Received float,
Answered float,
AvgWaitTime time(7),
AvgHandleTime time(7),
Abandoned float
```

When I am trying to import the data I am getting error in Input column date as sql is unable to convert it to date format. I surpassed this by creating a new table as per the suggestion given by sql. In the new table the data type for the date column is datetime. Then I got stuck in AvgWaitTime as is sql is unable to convert it to time format.

Is there a  way to convert all the required column data from source and then put it to destination? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever error you got didn't suggest to use a `datetime` column. If you want to parse a string, you need to use the appropriate transformation (eg Derived Column), not create new tables. BTW, if you want to store decimal values, use the `numeric` type, not float

Comment: You can change a column's type using the `Data Conversion` transform. The list of data types [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx). The date-only type is DT_DBDATE. For time(0) you can use DT_DBTIME, for time(7), DT_DBTIME2

Answer (score 1):

In the destination table you could change the type of the column date to string. It should work. Then you could use a derrived column placed in your task between the source and destination to change it back to date (type datetime, derrived column tab use replace). Untested code below:

```
> (DT_DATE)("20" + 
>     SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 1, 2)  + "-" + 
>     SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 3, 2)  + "-" +
>     SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 5, 2))
```